# Add check in SQL Server, based on a row value from a row connected by foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create the following 2 tables, in which the start date has to be before the end date:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentEntity 
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,    
    StartDate date NOT NULL,    
    EndDate date NOT NULL, 
    Description varchar(255)
); 

ALTER TABLE ParentEntity
  ADD CHECK (DATEDIFF(day,StartDate ,EndDate) > 0)

CREATE TABLE ChildEntity 
( 
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,    
    Parent int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ParentEntity (ID),    
    StartDate date NOT NULL,    
    EndDate date NOT NULL, 
    Description varchar(255)
); 

ALTER TABLE ChildEntity 
  ADD CHECK (DATEDIFF(day,StartDate ,EndDate) > 0)
```

Now I want to add this check: the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of each `ChildEntity` row must occur within the date interval between the `StartDate` and `EndDate` of the corresponding `ParentEntity` row.

How can I make this check? I do not know how to refer to the row which is defined by means of foreign key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use simple comparisons in the `CHECK`s rather than `DATEDIFF`.

If you want to reference values in columns of the parent table, you unfortunately need to duplicate the columns in the child. A FK with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` can take care of maintaining that data on an ongoing basis. You then need to decide whether you wish to expose the existence of these columns in the child table and how they get initially populated.

So, the basic one is:

```
CREATE TABLE ParentEntity ( 
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,    
    StartDate date NOT NULL,    
    EndDate date NOT NULL, 
    Description varchar(255),
    constraint UQ_ParentEntity_Dates UNIQUE (ID,StartDate,EndDate)
); 

ALTER TABLE ParentEntity
  ADD CHECK (StartDate < EndDate)

CREATE TABLE ChildEntity ( 
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,    
    Parent int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ParentEntity (ID),    
    StartDate date NOT NULL,    
    EndDate date NOT NULL, 
    Description varchar(255),
    ParentStart date NOT NULL,
    ParentEnd date NOT NULL,
    constraint FK_ChildParent FOREIGN KEY
      (Parent,ParentStart,ParentEnd) references ParentEntity
      (ID,StartDate,EndDate) ON UPDATE CASCADE
); 

ALTER TABLE ChildEntity 
  ADD CHECK (StartDate <EndDate)

ALTER TABLE ChildEntity
  ADD CHECK (StartDate >=ParentStart and EndDate <= ParentEnd)
```

If you wish to hide the existence of these additional columns in the child table, you can create a view and provide an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that populates these columns. You then have your callers use the view exclusively rather than the base table.

When doing this, you end up with a "super key" declared in the parent (here `ID`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` when just `ID` alone is a key) and a redundant foreign key constraint (the one on just `ID`). I usually leave this FK in place to document the "real" FK constraint between the tables. Some may choose to remove the redundant constraint.

(As a complete aside, I'd also recommend you use `constraint` clauses to introduce all of your constraints, PKs, FKs, UQs and CKs and take the opportunity to *name them*. It makes ongoing maintenance a lot easier. There's also no need to separate the `CHECK` constraints away from the initial `CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: What is the function of 'constraint UQ_ParentEntity_Dates UNIQUE (ID,StartDate,EndDate)', since I already have a ID defined as primary key? The short check is more elegant, I will definitely use that, and naming them is also good advice. Will the child only update when the parent is updated? What happens if I try to update the 'ParentStart' in the ChildEntity to a different value than the actual ParentEntity StartDate? Last question: I can have many ChildEntities per ParentEntity. I think that your example is updating the ID value of the Child, which should not happen, is that correct?

Comment: @DaniëlCamps - sorry, the FK should have been on `Parent, ParentStart, ParentEnd` rather than using `ID`. Corrected now. And the purpose of the `UNIQUE` constraint on the parent is to allow *all three of these columns* to be checked between the parent and the child, using the FK constraint.

Comment: I ended up naming all constraints, putting all constraint declarations inside the CREATE TABLE clauses, using the simpler date checks I am using the child-parent date check.